# Select a line that starts with one word (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to build two regular expressions that select :

1. Lines starting  with 'religion'. I try `/^religion/g` But I
       dont have results
2. Match dates and content. For example: `867.1.1 = {b_reykjavik = tb_shipyard_1}`
   I try `\d{3}\.([1-12])\.([1-31]) = {`  This selects `867.1.1 = {`.
   Now, how can I select  the other chars untill `}` ? Example: https://www.debuggex.com/r/GloZ8dZDVLJ5jc29

The text is:

```
# 1 - Vestisland
b_reykjavik = tribal    
#b_alftanes = city
#b_skalholt = temple
#b_pingvellir = castle
#b_kjalarnes = castle
#b_hvamm = castle
#b_hlidarendi = castle
#b_borg = castle    
# Misc
culture = norse
religion = zoroastrian
terrain = arctic

# History
867.1.1 = {
    b_reykjavik = tb_shipyard_1
}
900.1.1 = {
    b_reykjavik = castle
    b_reykjavik = ca_shipyard_1
    b_alftanes = city
}
1000.1.1 = {
    culture = norwegian
    religion = zoroastrian = sunni = catholic
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?:religion.*|\d+(?:\.\d+){2} = {[^}]*})/gm
```

See [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_E2X70Oa-67ueJEl)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line (since `m` modifier makes `^` match at the start of a line)
- `(?:religion.*` - Alternative 1: `religion` followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `|`  - or
- `\d+(?:\.\d+){2} = {[^}]*})` - 1+ digits, followed with 2 sequences of a `.` + one or more digits (see `\d+(?:\.\d+){2}`), then space, `=`, space, `{`, zero or more chars other than `}` (see `[^}]*`) and a `}`.

To only grab parts of those records, use capturing groups (`(...)`) around those subpatterns, see the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/nkmtyU/1):

```
/^(?:religion = (.*)|\d+(?:\.\d+){2} = {([^}]*)})/gm
                ^  ^                    ^     ^
```

```js
var rx = /^(?:religion = (.*)|\d+(?:\.\d+){2} = {([^}]*)})/gm;
var str = "# 1 - Vestisland\n\n# County Title\ntitle = c_vestisland\n\n# Settlements\nmax_settlements = 2\nb_reykjavik = tribal\n\n#b_alftanes = city\n#b_skalholt = temple\n#b_pingvellir = castle\n#b_kjalarnes = castle\n#b_hvamm = castle\n#b_hlidarendi = castle\n#b_borg = castle\n\n# Misc\nculture = norse\nreligion = zoroastrian\nterrain = arctic\n\n# History\n867.1.1 = {\n b_reykjavik = tb_shipyard_1\n}\n900.1.1 = {\n b_reykjavik = castle\n\n b_reykjavik = ca_shipyard_1 b_alftanes = city\n}\n1000.1.1 = {\n culture = norwegian\n religion = zoroastrian = sunni = catholic\n}";
console.log(str.match(rx));
```